# How to map mouse keys as keyboard keys without losing'numeric keypad' for Linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard, mouse, xmodmap

I know how to map mouse click for <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> (respectively left click, middle click, right click):

```
xkbset m   # required, but disable keypad
xmodmap -e "keycode 67 = Pointer_Button1 Pointer_Button1"
xmodmap -e "keycode 68 = Pointer_Button2"
xmodmap -e "keycode 69 = Pointer_Button3"
```

But this requires me to use `xkbset m` that use the [*slow keys*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_keys) mode :

If I press <kbd>4</kbd> from the keypad, it moves the cursor to the left. I don't need this feature, just the mapping above.

I tried to figure it out with `xdotool`, but I don't know how to handle key pressed/key released (for drag & drop) with

```
xdotool mousedown 1
xdotool mouseup 1
```

How can I **not** use this mode or how can I remap all keypad keys ?

What about the numeric and arithmetic signs from keypad please ?

Is there another solution ?

For information, needed for Debian (cinnamon) and Archlinux (xfce), and if possible, I would like a solution not based on the window manager.

## EDIT:

Tried [this solution](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/6901/mouse-button-press-hold-release-through-keyboard.1.html) but I can't drag and drop with <kbd>F1</kbd>.

In `~/.xbindkeysrc` :

```
"xdotool mousedown 1"
    F1
"xdotool mouseup 1"
    F1 + Release
```

Or :

```
"xdotool mousedown 1"
    m:0x10 + c:67
"xdotool mouseup 1"
    m:0x10 + c:67 + Release
```

Then :

```
xset -r 67
```

## EDIT2

Tried with [actkbd](https://github.com/thkala/actkbd)

```
# actkbd configuration file
<keycode ("67")> :key : :xdotool mousedown 1
<keycode ("67")> :rel : :xdotool mouseup 1
```

No cigar :/

Adapted from [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/using-keyboard-key-as-mouse-button-in-this-order-806473/)

Comment: Does xdotool do what you need?

Comment: The problem with xdotool is the key pressed, like drag and drop with left click. If you found a solution that is working with xdotool and drag&drop, I will accept it

Comment: Added solution that is not working for me with xdotool and xbindkeys

Comment: Added actkbd way with no luck :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**W00T !**

First : create a script `click`:

```
#!/bin/bash

id=$(
    xinput list |
        awk '/Dell USB Keyboard/{print gensub(/.*id=([0-9]+).*/, "\\1", "1")}'
)
xdotool mousedown $1
while IFS= read -r event; do
    if [[ $event == *release* ]]; then
        xdotool mouseup $1
        exit
    fi
done < <(xinput test $id)
```

Then add a new keyboard shortcut in your window manager and map <kbd>F1</kbd> to run `/path/to/mouse <1|3>` (left **OR** right click).

Et voilà ;)

This can be ran with `xbindkeys` to be WM agnostic

### Edit:

don't know why this doesn't work with archlinux + xfce 4.12 but on Debian9 + Cinnamon

### Edit  :

This solution works better :

In `.bashrc` :

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 67 = Pointer_Button1 Pointer_Button1"
xmodmap -e "keycode 68 = Pointer_Button2"
xmodmap -e "keycode 69 = Pointer_Button3"
```

As a keyboard shortcut :

```
#!/bin/bash

id=$(
    xinput list |
        awk '/Dell USB Keyboard/{print gensub(/.*id=([0-9]+).*/, "\\1", "1")}'
)


(
    while read event; do
        if [[ $event == *release* ]]; then
            xkbset -m
            exit
        fi
    done < <(xinput test $id)
) &
xkbset m
```

Comment: I think `xkbset m` is useless here. `xdotool` doesn't need it.

Comment: Fixed some minor bugs

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a "mouse toggle" action with this command in `.xbindkeysrc` (there is a typo in your first edit, it is not `.xbindkeys`):

```
"if [ ! -e /tmp/mouse_token ] ; then touch /tmp/mouse_token ; xdotool mousedown 1 ; else rm -f /tmp/mouse_token ; xdotool mouseup 1 ; fi"
some_key
```

It will create an empty file `/tmp/mouse_token` to keep track of the mouse button state. For `some_key` you may use `F1`, which means you will have to press it twice to get a single click, or use another key (e.g. `F4`).

Note: on my system, for an unknown reason, the press event for F keys does not trigger the xbindkeys binding, only the release event does. If the same happens on yours, use `release+F1` for `some_key`.

Note2: by default `xbindkeys` does not check `NumLock`, so you can drop the `m:0x10` modifier if you did not set `keystate_numlock = enable` in the rc file.

Comment: I already have a solution like this, but I would like to be able to really have a F1 key like left click, with the same behavior. Because I need F1 to do simple clicks and drag and drop with the same key. Moreover, the solution doesn't work

Comment: @MévatlavéKraspek OK, I understand. I also want to make clear that I tested my solution and it does work on my system (in case that's why you downvoted).